# Gulp ignore changes when pulling from git repo

Tags: node.js, git, github, gulp, browserify

We have a bunch of js files that are browserified and uglified.  Whenever I pull from github and have gulp running, it re-browserfies the files and adds them to my git history.  Is there anyway of Gulp knowing that the file changes came from a git pull?  Here is the relevant part from my gulpfile, it runs a custom build script when a file in static changes:

```
gulp.watch(paths.scripts, function(event){
    gulp_util.log('Starting', "'" + chalk.cyan('browserify') + "'...");
    var filename = path.basename(event.path)
    exec('node static_compile/js_compile ' + filename,
        {cwd: __dirname },
    function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if(error){
            gulp_util.log(chalk.red('File error'), error);
        }
        else{
            if(stderr != ''){
                gulp_util.log(chalk.red('Compile error'), stderr.replace('\n', ''));
            }
            else{
                gulp_util.log(
                    'Finished',
                    "'" + chalk.cyan('browserify') + "'",
                    'updated',
                    chalk.green(stdout.replace('\n', ''))
                );
                server.changed(event.path);
                gulp_util.log(chalk.red('Reloading'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's likely triggering your recompilation is changes to your `.git` directory, since git does not change files unless they've been changed upstream. Try adding `!.git` to your paths.scripts to ignore it.

Comment: Its listening to this path:
```scripts: ['static_compile/file_config.js', 'static_compile/modules/*.js']```.  .git is in the root directory, so It shouldn't affect it right?

Comment: Could you try updating just a readme from a different computer and then fetching with git pull. I seems odd that git would interfere with gulp.watch.

Comment: I don't think you understand, I WANT gulp to ignore files that are pulled from git.  It unnecessarily re-compiles them and since the browserify etc versions are different for different developers, they needlessly come up as modified.

Answer (score 0):

Your file system modifies the files whether it's git or your editor making the changes. One thing that comes to my mind would be a git pre-commit hook that suspends gulp watch until git finishes. But, that seems like a lot of trouble.